# Can't access admin panel for a website with CMS Made Simple: Class 'cms_cache_handler' not found

Tags: content-management-system, cmsmadesimple

I'm working on setting up and migration of old sites to a new server from Dreamhost. I have 130 sites to migrate. 1 is successful.  The version is: 1.12.1

The mods in the first site upgraded well. No problems. Have a procedure to migrate. That being said, the second site, as I followed my own documentation, fails when I try to access /admin/index.php

What I get is this below:

[image]

So, this is more informational than code... so please forgive me. I don't understand why CMS MADE SIMPLE is actually not simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems like an annoying issue. Forgive any repetition but here is what I would check:

- that is is 100% functioning on existing server
- correct php version 5.4.3+ (5.6+ recommended) on new server
- that all files & database are copied fully & without errors
- config.php settings are updated for new hosting & database
- that .htaccess, php.ini/.user.ini settings are appropriate
- check php error log
- are there any additional modules installed that may require additional php modules
- try more coffee or a nights sleep - both have helped me solve all sorts of issue in the past!

  - consider posting on CMSMS forum - will get a wider range of CMSMS users/experience and suggestions

Good luck

Chris

Comment: Chris, you da man... what I found out is that after 12 Caffeine patches, equivalent to 10 cups of coffee each, ludes and peyote, I found the solution along with what you stated.

After moving the site to a new server, I granted 777 perms on all folders and 644 on the Config.php file: Then I had to simply change the $config root_path (not root_url) to the "actual" server; /var/www/vhosts...etc....

Then I kept the .htaccess file as is and WHAMO! I was able to open Admin, clear the cache, reset the routing for all pages and reset the other thingy on the Site Admin. BOOM! The site opens....Ahhhhh

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what process you are using. So presuming that the site was working correctly on existing hosting and that the new hosting meets recommended requirements, especially PHP version:

1. Export database
2. Zip/Compress all website files into a single file
3. Copy zipped file to new hosting
4. Create new database & user with full access
5. Unzip files and make sure that they are in the right location (probably website root)
6. CHMOD config.php to 0644 and edit database, username & password settings for new hosting, CHMOD back to 0444
7. Make sure .htaccess is using correct settings for new hosting
8. Login to admin and clear cache

Sorry that the instructions are so basic, but the process really is Simple.

Possible issues can occur if:

- the PHP version is older than 5.4.3 (5.6+ recommended).
- files copied individually using ftp and some are corrupted/not copied.

Apart from that it is pretty straight forward.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm having another problem with another site I'm moving from Dreamhost to 1and1. I've dumped and reinstalled the site 4 times.  All the other sites work fine.  What doesn't work is this one particular site.  I cannot get the index.php to come up and what even more bizarre is that /admin/index.php goes to /admin/upgrade.php, but that page isn't there at all!  This company I'm working for, has 3 older versions of cmsms from 1.9.3 to 1.12.1 and nothing higher. It's installed for each site.  PHP will not render and I can't access the admin panel.